# Access Form AllowEdits = True does not enable editing of the form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I prevent editing of the records in the form to prevent accidental changes to the record. I do this in form current event I set Me.AllowEdits = False.

I have a button to allow edits. When the click the button I set Me.AllowEdits = True. However, users still cannot edit the record.

Is the Form Current event the wrong event to disable editing? Should I use a different event for that?

Comment: Form_Current fires when any record becomes current. You probably want to use the Form_Open event. (but if you intend to "reset" this back to disallow edits after saving or updating, then Form_Open won't take care of that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in a regular single & continuous form.

The Edit button must be inside the form, so it doesn't trigger the Current event when going from button to form controls.

```
' Allow editing
Private Sub cmdEdit_Click()
    Me.AllowEdits = True
End Sub

' Revert to not allow editing...

' ... after the current record has been saved
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    Me.AllowEdits = False
End Sub

' ... and after changing record (if user clicked Edit on another record, but didn't edit anything)
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.AllowEdits = False
End Sub
```